# Is there a way to sum data in Excel by group/category?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sum

I'm completely new to Excel and am actually using it for the first time for a math paper, so I'm pretty lost to start with.

I have a large spreadsheet of data. It's organized in a table with the headers: country code, country name, date, and total. The dates range from April, 2020 to March, 2021 for 203 countries.

What I'm trying to do is to take the total amounts from each country each day.

I've included some screenshots from my excel spreadsheet:

[image: List of dates from country, with total number for each day to the side]

Adding this data isn't so bad, right now I'm using the function =SUMIF(range, criteria (I'm just using ">0")). But when I have so much data to add, this feels really inefficient.

I was wondering if there was a function or if I could somehow create a function, that would let me input a country code and it would sum every row that has that country code? Or something similar that would speed up the process?

I'm sorry if this isn't the best-formatted question, it's my first time asking anything on Stack Overflow and I still new to the expectations from the community. Please let me know any extra information I can provide, ways I can clarify, or anything else.

Thank you to everyone in advance!

Comment: You can use a pivot table with filters.

Comment: you can also use SUMIF or SUMIFS

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you want to look at you can either use `SUMIF` / `SUMIFS` or a PIVOT table.

For your example above, I would recommend a PIVOT table. You can find further information on PIVOT tables [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/create-a-pivottable-to-analyze-worksheet-data-a9a84538-bfe9-40a9-a8e9-f99134456576). Simply drag and drop the values you want to have in each row / column into the respective fields.

In case you then want the result to look nice, you can find information on formatting PIVOT tables [here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/design-the-layout-and-format-of-a-pivottable-a9600265-95bf-4900-868e-641133c05a80)